# Problem retrieving multiple values from database using checkbox and submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page called shop, in the first part I call the categories to check them in the checkbox, in the second part below what is checked should be displayed, but I don't get any feedback when I press the submit button

When I put OR instead of AND, I get feedback, but when I want to mark the category sweatshirts and nike, I get everything that is in nike and all sweatshirts, and I want the feedback to be only NIKE SWEATSHIRTS

Here is my code

```
<div class="navigation_categories">
            <form>
            <div>
                <h2>Kategorije</h2>
                <?php
               
                $select_products = "SELECT * FROM category";
                $query_run  = mysqli_query($conn, $select_products);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
                {
                    foreach($query_run as $brandlist)
                    {
                        $checked = [];
                        if(isset($_GET['product_filter']))
                        {
                            $checked = $_GET['product_filter'];
                        }
                        ?>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="product_filter[]" value="<?= $brandlist['id']; ?>" 
                                    <?php if(in_array($brandlist['id'], $checked)){ echo "checked"; } ?>
                                 />
                                <?= $brandlist['name']; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Trenutno nema kategorija!";
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Pretrazi</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>


    </section>

   <div class="box-container">
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['product_filter'])) {
        $brand_checked = [];
        $brand_checked = $_GET['product_filter'];
        foreach($brand_checked as $brand_view) {
            //echo $brand_view;

            $select_products = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category IN ($brand_view) AND brand IN ($brand_view)";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $select_products);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0) {
                foreach($query_run as $items) :
                    ?>
                    <form action="" method="post" class="box">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?= $items['id']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $items['name']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?= $items['price']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?= $items['image_01']; ?>">
                        <button class="fas fa-heart" type="submit" name="add_to_wishlist"></button>
                        <a href="quick_view.php?pid=<?= $items['id']; ?>" class="fas fa-eye"></a>
                        <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $items['image_01']; ?>" alt="">
                        <div class="name"><?= $items['name']; ?></div>
                        <div class="flex">
                           <div class="price"><span></span><?= $items['price']; ?><span> /- rsd</span></div>
                           <input type="number" name="qty" class="qty" min="1" max="99" onkeypress="if(this.value.length == 2) return false;" value="1">
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Dodaj u korpu" class="btn" name="add_to_cart">
                    </form>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            }
        }
    } else {


        $select_products = "SELECT * FROM products ";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $select_products);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0) {
                foreach($query_run as $items) :
                    ?>
                    <form action="" method="post" class="box">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?= $items['id']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $items['name']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?= $items['price']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?= $items['image_01']; ?>">
                        <button class="fas fa-heart" type="submit" name="add_to_wishlist"></button>
                        <a href="quick_view.php?pid=<?= $items['id']; ?>" class="fas fa-eye"></a>
                        <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $items['image_01']; ?>" alt="">
                        <div class="name"><?= $items['name']; ?></div>
                        <div class="flex">
                           <div class="price"><span></span><?= $items['price']; ?><span> /- rsd</span></div>
                           <input type="number" name="qty" class="qty" min="1" max="99" onkeypress="if(this.value.length == 2) return false;" value="1">
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Dodaj u korpu" class="btn" name="add_to_cart">
                    </form>
            <?php
            endforeach;
    } else {
        echo '<p class="empty">0 products find!</p>';
    }
}
    ?>
   </div>

</section>
```

This is my category table

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Muskarci'),
(2, 'Zene'),
(3, 'Sport'),
(4, 'Majice'),
(5, 'Duksevi'),
(6, 'Jakne'),
(7, 'LifeStyle Patike'),
(8, 'Sportske Patike'),
(9, 'Ranac'),
(10, 'Teretana'),
(11, 'Lopte'),
(12, 'Nike'),
(13, 'Adidas'),
(14, 'Reebok'),
(15, 'Puma'),
(16, 'Trenerke');
```

and my product table

```
REATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `details` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `image_01` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image_02` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image_03` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `meta_tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `category`, `sub_cat`, `brand`, `name`, `details`, `price`, `image_01`, `image_02`, `image_03`, `meta_tag`) VALUES

(35,1,8,14, 'Muške Reebok Sport Patike', 'Muške Reebok patike za trčanje, sport.', 8400, 'muske_reebok_trcanje_1_1.png', 'muske_reebok_trcanje_1_2.png', 'muske_reebok_trcanje_1_3.png', 'muske sport patike,patike,reebok,sport,muske,muske patike, muške patike, muškarci,muskarci'),
(36,2,8,13, 'Ženske Adidas Sport Patike', 'Ženske patike za trčanje, sport', 12000, 'zenske_adidas_trcanje_1_1.png', 'zenske_adidas_trcanje_1_2.png', 'zenske_adidas_trcanje_1_3.png', 'zenske sport patike,patike,adidas,sport,zenske,zenske patike, ženske patike,žene,zene'),
(37,2,8,12, 'Ženske Nike Sport Patike', 'Ženske Nike patike za trčanje, sport.', 11699, 'zenske_nike_trcanje_1_1.png', 'zenske_nike_trcanje_1_2.png', 'zenske_nike_trcanje_1_3.png', 'zenske sport patike,patike,nike,sport,zenske,zenske patike, ženske patike,žene,zene'),
(38,2,8,14, 'Ženske Reebok Sport Patike', 'Ženske Reebok patike za trčanje, sport.', 8000, 'zenske_reebok_trcanje_1_1.jpg', 'zenske_reebok_trcanje_1_2.jpg', 'zenske_reebok_trcanje_1_3.jpg', 'zenske sport patike,patike,reebok,sport,zenske,zenske patike, ženske patike,žene,zene'),
(39,1,6,13, 'Muška Adidas Jakna', 'Adidas muška jakna', 16000, 'muske_jakne_adidas_13.png', 'muske_jakne_adidas_14.png', 'muske_jakne_adidas_15.png', 'jakna,jakne,adidas,jakne za zimu,muske,muške,muske jakne, muške jakne, muškarci,muskarci'),
(40,1,6,13, 'Muška Adidas Jakna', 'Muška Adidas Jakna', 15000, 'muske_jakne_adidas_23.png', 'muske_jakne_adidas_24.png', 'muske_jakne_adidas_25.png', 'jakna,jakne,adidas,jakne za zimu,muske,muške,muske jakne, muške jakne, muškarci,muskarci'),
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your $_GET['product_filter'] array, what your output is with your array values/filter and what your expected output is.

Comment: So if the selection is `Nike` and `sweatshirt`, then what is the value of `$brand_view`?

Comment: @FanoFN The value of $brand_view should be Nike+Sweatshirt but only Nike sweatshirts, and it throws me all nike products and all sweatshirts

Comment: @GRIV Example string: when I mark man , mark sweatshirt and mark nike I want my feedback to be only men's nike sweatshirts, and I constantly get it to list all men's products and then add all nike products and then insert all sweatshirts, so it lists we all from those categories

Comment: Ah I see. I don’t think you’re going to solve this by simply changing the query alone. Please see this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383801/e-commerce-product-filter-db-design)

Comment: I would also add

Answer (score -1):

On the line

```php
$select_products = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category IN ($brand_view) AND brand IN ($brand_view)";
```

try to change to

```php
$select_products = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $brand_view;";
```